# Printer in a AD double side printing

Tags: active-directory, print-server, network-printer

I've got a printer in my Active directory, but it's standard set to double sided printing but the problem is the printer doesn't support that so you have to switch it manually.

I've found the setting for the user, but it is automatically set to the original value if you reboot. Where can I find the setting in the active directory? The printer is a: **HP Color LaserJet CP1510 Series PCL 6**

(It's possible that there is a script for this but I don't know where to look.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model does support duplexing (double sided printing) though it is a manual process with a driver to support it.

I believe if you installed the printers on a DC then push them using a logon script or whatever to the workstations you should be able to just change the settings in printers on the DC and that should propagate to the workstations.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on the driver.  You should be able to set the default settings on the print server by setting the print server.  In theis case the HP driver has default settings that will match the settings on the shared printer.  Logon on to the print server, change the setting. Since this setting is also user-overrideable it's may not change on the client side.  If it doesn't you can either

1. Delete the shared printer and reshare it with an new name, this will force clients to use the new settings
2. change it on the users that have the issue but take comfort from the fact that new users will get the new settings